# Xcode bugged project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, breakpoints

I have a large project I've been working on for almost a year and it has several bugs that prevent me from working on it further.

1.) Breakpoints are ignored

2.) Several code blocks fail to execute as if they're being skipped over

I've made sure breakpoints are turned on, I'm not in release config, debug executable is checked, checked several settings to make sure symbols aren't being stripped etc...

Aside from completely blowing up the project, and starting anew what can I try?

Edit: Example of code blocks that don't execute:

```
if segue.identifier == "AboutLicense" {
  cleanup()
}
```

where `cleanup()` stops a timer and removes a subview, and executes normally when called elsewhere, but the segue is performed just fine.

Here's how the segue is called:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AboutLicense", sender: nil)
```

Then in my login controller, facebook login works, but there's NO console output, and any code I try to execute in the login button is ignored completely, though the facebook login completes.

```
  func facebookButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController : self) { loginResult in
      switch loginResult {
      case .failed(let error):
        print(error)
      case .cancelled:
        print("User cancelled login")
      case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
        print("Logged in")            
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show some code that doesn't execute properly.

Comment: it sounds like you are not using the Debug environment.

Comment: @LGP edited, thanks

Comment: @holex I'm in debug

Comment: Assuming you've done "due diligence" over the last year, try thinking outside of the box. In your first example, maybe the `if` isn't getting called at all. Maybe the segue identifier isn't what you think it is. Maybe the `performSegue` isn't getting hit. Maybe the function it's in isn't getting hit. It's brute-force, but add a bunch of `print` statement in code to see what *is* getting hit. And if all else fails, uninstall/reinstall Xcode *after* doing *Clean*, *Clean Build Folder*, and deleting your derived data.

Comment: What if you add a log statement and breakpoint to your app delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function?

Comment: (I'm beginning to suspect that your function isn't getting called at all.)

Comment: @dfd its several blocks, that's just an example. In the case of the segue, the `cleanup()` function isn't being called, but the segue IS performed - as you can see, with the same identifier. Nothing inside of that block will execute

Comment: @DuncanC breakpoints are ignored everywhere in the project

Comment: @DuncanC except a breakpoint did work there. I added a `print(application)` line which outputted to console

Comment: So breakpoints and print statements are not being ignored **everywhere**. It's sounding like your code is not being called.

Comment: Ok. So far it's been determined that (1) `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) works and (2) *possibly* nothing beyond that. Is there a storyboard? Is something defined in the project's *Deployment Info | Main Interface*? What's the name of the root view controller? Does it carry over to the class of the initial controller in the storyboard? *Do you see where I'm headed?* Create a new project, configure it as closely as possible to the one you say isn't working, and compare/contrast. It sounds like the issue *isn't* Xcode, it's the project.

Comment: I started with the LoginVC though the problem originated with a segue in a different file before LoginVC was created. I copied the code in LoginVC, deleted the file and created a new LoginVC, pasted the code in and the whole project is fine now... including the original segue bug where the cleanup() func wouldn't execute. I don't understand, but whatever. I'll take it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to recreate the project from scratch, but decided to start by recreating the files in the project first. I copied the code in `LoginVC`, deleted the file, created a new `LoginVC`, pasted the code back in, and the whole project runs as expected now. Breakpoints and code execute as expected throughout the project

Comment: this answer doesn't explain what was causing the problem nor the fix. All it shows is that you recreated the files.

Comment: @LanceSamaria Going through my answers and downvoting them because I downvoted one of yours?

Comment: someone delete my original comment but I only left a comment, I never downvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to set optimization level to -Onone.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also try cleaning the project and deleting the derived data folder.